# Android AWS sdk not able to upload

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have created app on MobileHub and integrated for android. The configuration file is in raw directory.

After calling

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(context).execute();
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, KEY_SECRET);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                    .s3Client(s3Client)
                    .build();



TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                            transferUtility.upload(
                                    BUCKET_NAME,
                                    file.getName(),
                                    file);

uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                            System.out.println("State changed:"+state);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                            System.out.println("Progress.."+bytesCurrent);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("error:"+ex);
                        }
                    });
```

I get

```
Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully.
AWSMobileClient Initialize succeeded.
```

But when I am trying to upload any file(from public directory and private both), it only triggers onProgressChanged once, with the TransferState as IN_PROGRESS. And nothing else.

If it is unable to upload image, shouldn't there be a proper error?

My Logcat:

`06-12 14:22:41.873 I: Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully.
06-12 14:22:41.873 D: AWSMobileClient Initialize succeeded.
06-12 14:22:41.873 I: Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully.
06-12 14:22:41.877 I: registering receiver
06-12 14:22:41.955 I: State changed:IN_PROGRESS
06-12 14:22:41.960 W: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
    finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
    finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-12 14:22:46.844 V: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
06-12 14:22:46.845 I: Sending crashes
06-12 14:23:18.221 V: Recording user engagement, ms: 36408
06-12 14:23:18.223 V: Connecting to remote service
06-12 14:23:18.230 V: Activity paused, time: 22740592
06-12 14:23:18.237 D: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=36408, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AdminActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1968217097067733732}]`

Comment: past your logcat

Comment: @MilanPansuriya done

Comment: have you defined broadcast receiver in your manifest?

Comment: `<service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />` I only added this service, as suggested in API

Comment: What device and Android Platform version are you using?

Comment: MotoG5 s+. Android Nougat. Build tools v27.1.1. I have tried this in Marshmallow as well.

Comment: Does this happen for files of all sizes, types, and names? or for certain files? What network are you on? What version of the AWS Android SDK are you using? The state is set to WAITING_FOR_NETWORK when the network is offline. When network comes back online, we automatically resume the transfer.

Comment: @Karthikeyan 2.6.22 is the aws sdk version. No, it is same for all files irrespective of file size. And I'm keeping the connection on. Network access permissions have been given

Comment: Problem was with the proguard. In build.gradle, when i removed, `minifyEnabled true` `shrinkResources true`, it started working. Probably some proguard rule need to be added.

Comment: Thanks, Mukkaram Ali for confirming. We will check the proguard rules and find out what's the problem.